# Using Cocoa with AppleScript

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, applescript-objc, nsworkspace

Having some trouble calling Cocoa methods from within AppleScript. For example, running the following snippet of code produces an error when ran using `osascript`:

```
set sharedWorkspace to call method "sharedWorkspace" of class "NSWorkspace"
```

Here's the thrown exception: `Expected “,” but found identifier. (-2741)` Should this code be nested under a tell statement? If so, what application should I be talking to?

Thanks.

Comment: `call method` is AppleScript Studio syntax. This SDK has been abandoned about 10 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call method` looks like something out of the old **AppleScript Studio**, which was deprecated in 10.6 Snow Leopard and has since been removed.

There are a couple of prerequisites for calling Cocoa methods - a regular script needs to declare that it uses the desired framework(s), and the various classes and enums are defined at the application level and thus need to be prefaced with `current application`, or an object needs to exist to send the message to.

With that said, Cocoa methods can be called in a few different ways - using your snippet, for example:

```
use framework "Foundation"

set sharedWorkspace to current application's NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace
-- or --
set sharedWorkspace to sharedWorkspace of current application's NSWorkSpace
-- or --
tell current application's NSSharedWorkspace's sharedWorkspace
    set sharedWorkspace to it
end tell
```

The first form is what you will normally see used, as it is the closest to the Objective-C form.  The appendix in the [Mac Automation Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AppendixA-AppleScriptObjCQuickTranslationGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH79-SW1) has more information about translating from  the Objective-C documentation, which is what Apple expects you to use.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
set sharedWorkspace to current application's NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace()
```